# HttpClient request to payment gateway working on localhost but not on godaddy server

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.webexception

I am calling payment gateway with the http of HTTPclient request.

My code is working fine from localhost but not on server.

From localhost `StatusCode` is OK

From godaddy server this is the error received:

> An error occurred while sending the request.System.Net.WebException:
> Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond xxx.xx.xx.xx:443 at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect

Can someone guide me towards the possible reason for this and solution too

Comment: If you are running from a shared GoDaddy host it could be that the connection is blocked by either the payment server or GoDaddy itself. You should raise a support ticket with both.

Comment: I also wouldn't use shared hosting for any site that requires payment and does the credit card processing itself. There be dragons.

Comment: Thanks, but i talked to both parties and both of them are claiming that there is not firewall rule etc in order to block requests. Any other suggestion if there is no option other than using shared hosting

Comment: I'd recommend to migrate to another service provider. There is no guarantee that it would work there either.

Comment: Also it would help greatly if you added the part of the code which is throwing this error.

Comment: And also check for typos on the host name.